# Power Brake Booster Removal

Tags: honda, accord, brake-booster

Can someone please explain the easiest way to remove a Power Brake Booster from a 1994 Honda Accord Wagon lx.  everything has been dismantled.  the hard part here is the removal only part.  there isn't enough space to pull the booster out and away from the car.  It looks like my air intake manifold is in the way and I may have to remove my AIM to get the job done but I don't want to do that and so in the meantime I'll cut-off the latch bolt from the old booster to see if I can gain some space to move the Booster around and slide it out.  If someone knows an easier way Please let us know.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to do this without removing the intake manifold. Move all the hoses, wires and cables out of the way. Move the clutch reservoir and bracket if it has a manual transmission. Pull the booster out and then rotate it clockwise about 90 degrees so that the operating rod is facing the fender. It is a tight squeeze but it can be done.

Comment: Thank you Fred.  I'm going to try again to see if I can jiggle it out and I made up my mind.  If I cannot get it out  then I'll be removing the AIM manifold to save on time.  Been without for a month  I need it now!     There are only about 8 bolts to remove and a gasket to replace.